# SimpleDateFormat throws exception on a real phone but works correctly on an emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, simpledateformat, parseexception

Trying to format date and put it into TextView in Android Studio from

> Mon, 29 Feb 2016 22:31:00 GMT

to

> 2016-02-29 22:31:00

In my Genymotion Google Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy S5, etc devices it looks perfect. When i run this application on a real phone(not just one) TextView with date was empty: getFormatPubDate throws ParseException with "Unparseable date" on

```
 date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z").parse(pubDate);
```

Date in pubDate variable is correct and not null.

```
// strings.xml
    <string name="data_time_format">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</string>

// someClass.java
    public String getFormatPubDate(String format){
                try {
                Date date = null;
                    date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z").parse(pubDate);
                    return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return pubDate;
            }

// someActivity.java    
viewHolder.timePublishedTextView.setText(cachedNews.getFormatPubDate(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.data_time_format)));
```

> P.S. I use format with HH (24 hour) but time is not correct.  Example
>   from emulator - Mon, 29 Feb 2016 23:01:00 GMT formated to 2016-02-29
>   18:01:00

Comment: Indeed, "EEE", "MMM" and "z" are locale-sensitive. Use `Locale.ENGLISH` as extra parameter in construction of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //This is original date format
 String date = "Mon, 29 Feb 2016 22:31:00";

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            Locale.ENGLISH);

 //This is new date format
 SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

 Date parsedDate = null;

 try 
 {
     parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 String text = print.format(parsedDate);
```